# My app is crashing on iOS 10 and earlier. Where can I start looking to debug this?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10

App's working fine in the newer iOS versions. On iOS 10 and earlier it crashes immediately after showing the splash screen. Any ideas as to where I can start looking (pretty new to working with Xcode)? Here's an excerpt of the console log where it crashes:

```
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d897b0b   exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d2fc141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d907134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132 
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d81e840 __forwarding + 1024 
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d81e3b8._CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120 
    5   immortalyyc                         0x0000000107116fe3 -[RunnerViewController viewDidLoad] + 307
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010c042d38 -[UIViewController awakeFromNib] + 129
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010c2ab5f8 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2425
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c2ad614 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 222
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010bea37ea -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 75
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010bea3e13 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010bea24b6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1407
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010be9f7f3 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 182
    13  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001114425f6 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011144246d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 186
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001114427f6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e17ec01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e1640cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e1635ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e163016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010be9e08f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010bea4134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    22  immortalyyc                         0x0000000107b7265b main + 75
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e75665d start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: deployment target is ios 8. Here's the code snippet that pops up when the simulator crashes (devices also crash, not just the simulator) :

Comment: 0x106355656 <+70>:  callq  0x1063d2e92               ; symbol stub for: UIApplicationMain
    0x10635565b <+75>:  movl   %eax, %ebx
    0x10635565d <+77>:  movq   0x174494(%rip), %rsi      ; "release

Comment: You need to look for the exception message.  What are the locations in the stack frames before 6?

Comment: (
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d897b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d2fc141 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d907134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d81e840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d81e3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
 5   immortalyyc                         0x0000000107116fe3 -[RunnerViewController viewDidLoad] + 307

Comment: In your `viewDidLoad` function of `RunnerViewController` you are calling a function that is not available on iOS 10 or earlier.  [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54974336/edit) your question to include this code.   The exception message will tell you which function you tried to call and on what object.

Comment: Got it, fixed the error! Thanks for your help (with both stack overflow and xcode)

Comment: Please do not post details in comments. Please edit your question with all relevant details.